# Clover as code coverage tool for android:

Tags: android

Clover as code coverage tool for android: Followed steps from website https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Clover-for-Android. While I was running my project, getting an error as follows : An internal error occurred during: Clover Coverage Monitor. gc overhead limit exceeded. I found that their clover.jar is of 14.4MB and so increased the MaxPermSize in eclipse.ini to 2048m. Still caught with the same error. Please help me how to solve this problem.

Comment: What build tool are you using? Make sure Clover is only used for in testing scope and doesn't get packaged when building.

Comment: Clover doesn't get packaged for java applications. When clover is used for android and as per the link mentioned in the above question, clover.jar is included in the package, so that no instrumentation test cases are not required and coverage will be done on the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

> I found that their clover.jar is of 14.4MB

Did you use Clover-for-Eclipse or Clover-for-Android? I'm asking, because Clover-for-Android contains reduced Clover runtime (180kb instead of 14.4MB). Please check if you have plugins\com.cenqua.clover.runtime_3.1.7.v20120920000000.jar in project's class path.